# Strategy & builder design patterns and templates in C++

Tags: c++, geometry, builder, strategy-pattern

The following is the `geometry` class, which handles storing and manipulating vertex and index information of a particular 3-dimensional object.

```
class geometry {
public:
    geometry();
    ~geometry();

    unsigned int get_face_count();
    unsigned int get_vertex_count();

    void add_vertex(vertex v);
    void add_face(face f);

    void remove_vertex(unsigned int idx);
    void remove_face(unsigned int idx);

    std::vector<vertex>& get_vdata();
    std::vector<face>& get_fdata();

    vertex& get_vertex(unsigned int idx);
    vertex& get_face(unsigned int idx);

    void clear();
    void calc_normals();

    bool is_empty() const;
protected:
    std::vector<vertex> vertices;
    std::vector<face> faces;
};
```

The following is a base Builder class, which can't be instantiated:

```
class geometry_creator : public geometry {
    protected:
        bool normalsWerePredefined;
        /* Unused */
        bool texturesWerePredefined;
    public:
        geometry* build();
};
```

The `build();` method for all derived Builder classes are the same, which looks like this (for context):

```
/* Liskov principle (upcasting) */
geometry* geometry_creator::build() {
    if (!normalsWerePredefined) calc_normals();
    geometry* g = new geometry(*this);
    return g;
}
```

Next is the `geometry_obj` class, which inherits `geometry_creator` (Builder). This class is responsible for building a `geometry` object from a specified .OBJ file. I created a builder class because there exists other ways to build `geometry` objects, such as procedural methods.

```
class geometry_obj : public geometry_creator {
private:
    std::string filename;
    std::fstream file;
    std::stringstream stream;
    std::string element;
    enum entry {
        VERTEX,
        VERTEX_TEXTURES,
        VERTEX_NORMALS,
        FACE
    };
    inline static const std::map<std::string, entry> map = {
        {"v", VERTEX},
        {"vt", VERTEX_TEXTURES},
        {"vn", VERTEX_NORMALS},
        {"f", FACE}
    };
    /* Our strategies. */
    vec_strategy<3, float> vec3f_strategy;
    vec_strategy<2, float> vec2f_strategy;
    vec_strategy<3, unsigned int> vec3i_strategy;
protected:
    unsigned int vIndex, vnIndex, vtIndex, fIndex;
public:
    geometry_obj(std::string filename);
};
```

The `vec_strategy` members give us the context for my question.
Lastly, the next two classes define the interface for a particular Strategy and then the concrete Strategy class.

```
template<typename T>
    /* Strategy interface. */
    class objreader_strategy {
    public:
        virtual T execute(std::stringstream& stream) = 0;
    };
    
    /* Concrete strategy implementation. */
    /* int L is data length, typename S is datatype of data to acquire. */
    template<int L, typename S>
    class vec_strategy : objreader_strategy<glm::vec<L, S>>{
    private:
        std::array<S, L> _data;
    public:
        vec_strategy();
        ~vec_strategy() = default;

        virtual glm::vec<L, S> execute(std::stringstream& stream);
};
```

In most Strategy design pattern implementations, the Context (our derived Builder class `geometry_obj`) has a `setStrategy` method and `executeStrategy` method. With this implementation I could not find a way to create a method parameter that could handle a base pointer to `obj_strategy` for `setStrategy` nor a way to store a theoretical `currentStrategy` member, given the relatively complex template parameters.

**My question is now**: what solution exists to store a `currentStrategy` object in the given context (templates for T, L, and S)? What better method exists to prevent the instantiation of multiple `vec_strategy` objects in the `geometry_obj` class, and instead use one member that certain methods in `geometry_obj` could act upon when needed?

I have not tested to see if this code runs as expected yet, but it does compile. So part of my question also asks: how well is this program designed? - from your perspective.

If any additional context is required, such as implementation of these classes, I would gladly provide it. I'm also terribly sorry for my naming conventions.

Comment: The 3 entities in the Strategy pattern are 1/ the Strategy interface (typically an abstract base class), 2/ the concrete Strategy subclass implementations, and 3/ the Context which uses the provided concrete strategy via a reference to the base class. You haven't written the abstract base class, and it's not obvious how you can use this pattern with 1 of the 3 core entities omitted.

Comment: The closest you have are the various `objreader_strategy<glm::vec<3, float>>` etc., but they should ideally have _names_, and the context should be storing references to those base classes. Not concrete instances of the derived types.

Comment: As a minor aside, why on earth should we say `geometry_creator` IS-A `geometry`? That seems extremely odd.

Comment: @Useless 1. How do I go about storing references to those base classes?, and 2. ``geometry_creator`` IS-A ``geometry`` because ``geometry`` already details all of the methods of adding, removing, and manipulating the desired vertex and index lists.

Comment: I realize that those methods for adding, removing, and manipulating vertex and index lists could just be moved to the ``geometry_creator`` interface and wouldn't make much of a difference, since in my application I never **directly** add, remove, or manipulate a ``geometry``'s vertices and indices outside the scope of child ``geometry_creator`` objects.